# Server on different ip's

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to create TCP Server that should run on a machine with multiple NIC's (eth0, eth1). Each NIC has its own IP from the network and I basically want to be able to connect to the servers running on each of the IP's at the same time. However currently I am able only to connect (netcat) to the first interface IP eth0 and when I try with eth1 I get a "Connection refused" even when I have the server only running on eth1.

I'm not sure if it is a problem with my server code (below). I bind to the required interface with setsockopt() and also use the interface IP (retrieved via ioctl), and netstat shows that the server is listening on the correct ip:port, however I am not able to connect to the one on eth1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 255

struct in_addr getIfIp(char* ifName)
{
  int sockfd;
  struct ifreq ifr;

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
  strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
  if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ioctl failed\n");
  }
  close(sockfd);

  return ((struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr;
}

int startServer(char* ifName, unsigned short port)
{
  int sock_descriptor, conn_desc;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;
  socklen_t size = sizeof(client_addr);
  char buff[MAX_SIZE];

  if (ifName == NULL || port == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid server parameters\n");
    return -1;
  }

  sock_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sock_descriptor < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed creating socket\n");
    return sock_descriptor;
  }

  if (setsockopt(sock_descriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ifName, strlen(ifName)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed setting socket option\n");
    return -1;
  }

  bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // AddressFamily = Internet address
  serv_addr.sin_addr = getIfIp(ifName);//INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  // bind the address to the socket file descriptor
  if (bind(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to bind\n");
    return -1;
  } else {
    printf("bound to %s\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr));
  }

  // Now start listening
  if (listen(sock_descriptor, 0) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Listen failed");
    return -1;
  } else {// max queue of pending connections
    printf("Listening on port %hu ...\n", port);
  }    
  conn_desc = accept(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &size);   
  if (conn_desc == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed accepting connection\n");
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Connected\n");
  }

  close(conn_desc);
  close(sock_descriptor);
  return 0;
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

[EDIT]
As mentioned in my comment, one funny thing I noticed is that once I connect to either of the interfaces I can only connect to this interface again and connect attempts to the other fail (for both eth0 and eth1) until a reboot.
Also I guess I would go ahead with INADDR_ANY for now but would really like to hear if anyone could shed some light as to why I can't connect to separate listeners (with my code here) in this case?

Comment: print out the IP address your getIfIp() function returns(with e.g. inet_ntop() ), and check that it gives you the correct one. (Also check that all the calls, e.g. the ioctl() call succeed)

Comment: Yeah have that just removed it here to reduce the clutter. It does print out the right one.

Comment: Then issue `netstat -apn` and see what it says about your socket. If it's listening at the correct IP address/port, and the client is connecting to that IP address/port, it's a networking problem, e.g.  a firewall or routing issues.

Comment: netstat shows its listening at the correct ip:port. One funny thing I noticed is that the interface I connect to first is the only one that works subsequently (I rebooted and connected to eth1 first and now can't seem to connect to eth0's IP now). BTW added the checks also.

Comment: So it's probably a routing issue, you're doing something strange, e.g. having two IP addresses on your machine, both on the same subnet or similar - or running two IP subnets on the same ethernet segment which causes issues with ARP with the default setting on linux at least

Comment: Yes for now both IP's are from the same DHCP server (same subnet). Would be nice to hear why it won't work in this case?

Comment: Because the routing table will normally be set up to use only one of the network cards for that subnet, so packets go out the wrong interface, and get the wrong addresses.

Answer (score 1):

To have the socket listen on any interface use `INADDR_ANY` as listener address ...

```
serv_addr.sin_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

and remove the call to `setsockopt()`.

---

I'm not sure whether a back-log size of `0` makes sense. Also the code misses to test the outcome of the call to `listen()`.

---

Finally `int size` should be `socklen_t size`.

Comment: I want this on specific interfaces at the same port number (as its a server) so I can connect to either one as required or at the same time, which is why it is bound to the specific interface's IP.

Comment: A backlog of zero will be adjusted upwards by the platform.

Comment: @source.rar: If you bind to `INADDR_ANY`, the server socket will listen/accept on all available IP interfaces. After a client connects, you can use `getsockname()` to find out which interface/IP the client connected to. But if you bind to a specific interface/IP then the server socket will be able to listen/accept only on that specific interface/IP. To bind to multiple interfaces/IPs explicitly, you would have to create a separate listening socket for each one. For what you have described, bind to `INADDR_ANY`, unless you are trying to ignore particular interfaces/IPs.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the latter (separate listening socket for each interface) with my code shown above.